# The Maximum and Minimum Functions of Two Functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have two functions `f(x,y)=1 + 2*x +3*y^3` and `g(x,y)=y + x^2`. I want to have maximum function of  `{f(x,y)+g(x,y), f(x,y)*g(x,y)}` on `0<=x<=1`.
For example to two functions of one variable: I need criterion of green function in the following picture:
[image]

I want to create a new function, such as `h[x_,y_]:=Max[f[x,y]+g[x,y],f[x,y]*g[x,y]]`

Comment: Neither your functions nor your goals are clear.  What is `t`? What does "have maximum function" mean?  Do you want to create a new function, such as `h[x_,y_]:=Max[f[x,y]+g[x,y],f[x,y]*g[x,y]]`? Or do you want a function of `y` given constrained maximization over `x`?  Or do you just need to graph something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for something like the following.  Define the functions `f` and `g`

```
f[x_, y_] := 1 + 2*x + 3*y^3
g[x_, y_] := y + x^2
```

Define a function that finds the maximum as a function of `y`.  I can't see an easy way to do this for symbolic values of `y`, so I define a function that evaluates only when given a numerical value.

```
h[y_?NumericQ] := 
 MaxValue[{Max[f[x, y] + g[x, y], f[x, y] g[x, y]], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

As a check, compute a table of values

```
Table[{y, h[y]}, {y, 0, 1, 1/4}]
(* {{0, 4}, {1/4, 275/64}, {1/2, 81/16}, {3/4, 1911/256}, {1, 
  12}} *)
```