# Function of Maximum and Minimum Functions of Two Functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I try to answer this question [The Maximum and Minimum Functions of Two Functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209152/the-maximum-and-minimum-functions-of-two-functions/209163#209163)

I wrote the following code

```
f[x_, y_] := 1 + 2*x + 3*y^3
g[x_, y_] := y + x^2
maxi[x_, y_] := 
 Refine[{(f[x, y] + g[x, y])/2 + Abs[f[x, y] - g[x, y]]/2}, 
  Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}]
Plot3D[maxi[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Is there any way to find function of `maxi`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Simplify[(f[x, y] + g[x, y])/2 + Abs[f[x, y] - g[x, y]]/2,0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1]
```

which instantly returns

```
1+2 x+3 y^3
```

You can see that by inspection because `f[x,y]>g[x,y]` over the domain so the `Abs` does nothing and disappears and that leaves `f[x,y]/2+g[x,y]/2+f/x,y]/2-g[x,y]/2==f[x,y]`

Comment: Many thanks. But your answer does not work for: `f[x_] := x^2` and 
`g[x_] := 1 - x`, `maxi1[x_] = 
  Refine[{(f[x] + g[x])/2 + Abs[f[x] - g[x]]/2}, 
   Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1}];` and `Simplify[maxi1[x], 0 <= x <= 1]`.

Comment: @bahram If you change the question then the answer usually changes. Try this for your new f and g: `f[x_] := x^2; g[x_] := 1 - x; list={{f[x],Reduce[f[x]>=g[x]&&0<=x<=1,x]}, {g[x],Reduce[f[x]<=g[x]&&0<=x<=1,x]}};
Piecewise[list]` which gives you a `Piecewise` function that is the maximum of f and g over the domain. The minimum can be obtained  in the same way. But I suspect this answer will not be satisfactory for you either.